# select count(ID) where ID IN a or b

Tags: sql, oracle, count, database-performance

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to get a weekly COUNT of every ID that meets criteria A OR criteria B.

```
  select CREATE_WEEK, count ( A.PK )
 from TABLE1 A
where    ( A.PK not in (select distinct ( B.FK )
                                    from TABLE2 B
                                  where B.CREATE_TIMESTAMP > '01-Jan-2013')
              or A.PK in (select A.PK
                                 from ( select A.PK, A.CREATE_TIMESTAMP as A_CRT, min ( B.CREATE_TIMESTAMP ) as FIRST_B
                                              from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
                                             where    A.PK = B.FK
                                                     and A.CREATE_TIMESTAMP > '01-Jan-2013'
                                                     and B.CREATE_TIMESTAMP > '01-Jan-2013'
                                         group by A.PK, A.CREATE_TIMESTAMP)
                                where A_CRT < FIRST_B) )
        and A.CREATE_TIMESTAMP > '01-Jan-2013'
        and CREATE_WEEK >= 2
        and THIS_WEEK - CREATE_WEEK >= 1
group by CREATE_WEEK 
order by CREATE_WEEK asc
```

**Note: PK in table1 = FK in table2, so in the first subquery, I'm checking whether the PK from table1 exists as FK in table2. Week comes from TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (TRUNC (A.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, 'IW')), 'IW')

When I take out the OR and run the query on either subquery the results are returned in 1-2 seconds.  But when I try to run the combined query, the results aren't returned after 20 minutes.

I know I can run them separately and then sum them in a spreadsheet, but I'd rather just get one number.

Comment: which DB and version of DB?

Comment: "I know I can run them separately and then sum them in a spreadsheet,": If any IDs are not present in subquery A, but are in subquery B, they will be counted twice if you do that. And just because *you* know that that won't be the case, doesn't mean the database knows. The database has to check that in order to give you the correct result, and unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing so in the most efficient way possible.

Comment: This is a performance-related question. You need to determine what is causing the poor performance - i.e. examine the query plans to see what changes. For example, the query without the OR might be doing some kind of hash anti-join (i.e. running the subquery once, then doing a scan across `table`), and the query with the OR might be doing a nested loop join on the two subqueries (`A` and `B`) for each row in `table`.

Comment: Difficult to answer performance questions without the complete code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I'm using a union in the interim, but that requires summing in the spreadsheet.  I'd rather avoid that and just get the sum directly.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka - Oracle 11. I'm working through Toad.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - i added the full code.
@JeffreyKemp - the explain plan shows 
`SELECT STATEMENT ALL_ROWS       
 12 HASH GROUP BY      
  11 FILTER      
   1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE table1    
   3 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE table2    
    2 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX table2_FK01   
   10 FILTER     
    9 HASH GROUP BY   
     8 NESTED LOOPS   
      6 NESTED LOOPS 
       4 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE table2
       5 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) table1_PK 
      7 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE table1 
`
each table has about 2.5 million records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get a weekly COUNT of every ID that meets criteria A OR criteria B

However your code is:

```
ID NOT IN (subquery A) OR ID IN (subquery B)
```

The NOT is at odds with your requirement.

Assuming you ID's that meet both criteria, use:

```
ID in (
  select ... -- this is subquery A
  union
  select ... -- this is subquery B)
```